# Is there any benefit in setting properties in an xml file rather than a java class?

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, annotations

I'm working with a project which uses hibernate and has set the properties of hibernate like dialect in a java class(named DoahibernateUtil) rather than an xml file, I'm wondering why the programmer hasn't used an xml file? 
My second question is, why in the hibernate folder there isn't neither an xml file to map the data base table to the program, is this line mapping the Table to the program instead of that xml file?

```
AnnotationConfiguration cfg = new AnnotationConfiguration()
    .addAnnotatedClass(mehad.entities.LogTable.class)
```

Comment: Consider the possibility that once you'll need to update the properties. If it's in a .java class, you 'll need to recompile, re-release, re-deploy , ....
if it's in an .xml file, you just need to change the .xml and restart your server.

Comment: Xml is painful, and xml-heavy projects tend to be more brittle from a refactoring standpoint.  It looks like your programmer/project is using annotation-based configuration instead, which is preferable to xml in virtually any case I can think of.  When configuration lives alongside the code it relates to, that's a good thing.

Comment: @aroth what's your view on the Stultuske idea? how about udating the properties?

Comment: Agree with @Stultuske more: if you have some soft configuration for application you can re-parse configuration.xml to load new configuration session wise or application wise as well. You do not need to restart :)

Comment: @shakiba - When I build a Java project, the end result/deployable is a single WAR file.  So a rebuild is still needed, even for a change to an xml file (if you're doing proper deployment management, anyways).  Yes, you can make ad-hoc changes by going into the server's deployment folders and editing/replacing xml files and then restarting the server/reparsing the xml, but I see little benefit in doing so.  Ideally you should have a 'one-click' (or one-command) build/deploy process anyways, and at this point compiling Java is probably faster than manually moving files around anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pros of xml:

- no need to rebuild the application to change the mapping
- your entities source code is clean and no need to depend explicitly from Hibernate

Pros of annotations:

- the mapping is more readable
- the mapping goes with the code, so it's easier to mantain

Comment: what about my second question? ;)

Comment: Regarding the second pro, surely other JPA providers also support annotation-based config, so long as you avoid relying upon hibernate-specific annotations?

Comment: @shakiba in that code you are adding an annotated class to a configuration. It won't use the XML file. If this doesn't help please clarify your question

Comment: @aroth anyway it would add another dependency to your code

Comment: @onof well as far as I've read in different tutorials there should an xml file with extension .hbm that is used to map the tables to our program, I'm asking since there isn't any xml files, is that code doing the same thing?

Comment: Yes, you can use the XML file or the annotations. To use the HBM based configuration you must create the file like this: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration

Answer (score 0):

Another factor is that changing a configuration file is safer than changing Java source code. There might be people whom you trust to fiddle with the configuration file but don't trust to fiddle with the source code.

Comment: That can cut both ways, particularly if your xml file needs to reference fully-qualified class-names for things in the source-code (or third-party libs).  It's very easy to make a mistake with that, and instead of a compiler error in the editor you'll usually end up with a stack-trace upon starting up the server (typically a nested one with a `NoClassDefFoundError` at its root).